# "Incorrect string value" when trying to insert UTF-8 into MySQL via JDBC?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, utf-8, utf8mb4

This is how my connection is set:
`Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName + "?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8", userName, password);`

And I'm getting the following error when tyring to add a row to a table:
`Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x90\x8D\x83\xF0\x90...' for column 'content' at row 1`

I'm inserting thousands of records, and I always get this error when the text contains \xF0 (i.e. the the incorrect string value always starts with \xF0).

The column's collation is utf8_general_ci.

What could be the problem?

Comment: That would be LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH TILDE (ñ).

Comment: For others encounter this issue, you could try:
On the database: 
ALTER DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
- It will solve the” from now on “ created tables. NOT for EXIST tables. For them you need to do :
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
Source - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/any-way-to-disable-charset-handshake-and-change-default-server-charset-in-managed-mysql

Comment: Tried the approach by @lingar Just to make the reader aware, this screws up performance of the table very very very badly. So badly that I had to revert the table back to utf8.
Looking for another approach.

Comment: The performance hit was most likely from creating a variance in charset with indexes. One index is latin the other is utf8mb4, index will not work correctly. You will need to set any joined columns as the same charset.

Answer (score 404, accepted):

MySQL's `utf8` permits only the Unicode characters that can be represented with 3 bytes in UTF-8. Here you have a character that needs 4 bytes: \xF0\x90\x8D\x83 ([U+10343 GOTHIC LETTER SAUIL](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10343/index.htm)).

If you have MySQL 5.5 or later you can change the column encoding from `utf8` to [`utf8mb4`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html). This encoding allows storage of characters that occupy 4 bytes in UTF-8.

You may also have to set the server property `character_set_server` to `utf8mb4` in the MySQL configuration file. It seems that [Connector/J defaults to 3-byte Unicode otherwise](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html):

> For example, to use 4-byte UTF-8 character sets with Connector/J, configure the MySQL server with `character_set_server=utf8mb4`, and leave `characterEncoding` out of the Connector/J connection string. Connector/J will then autodetect the UTF-8 setting.

Comment: What an odd choice to have utf8 really mean "the subset of UTF8 that can be represented in 3 bytes".

Comment: @EricJ. Exactly! This is very confusing: I knew my encoding and collation were `utf8_general_ci` but was still getting a mysql error. I'm glad @Joni had the answer above or else I would have never guessed what was going on.

Comment: Warning: You should upgrade to the newest version of the Connector/J driver when doing this since older versions don't seem to autodetect the utf8mb4 setting correctly!

Comment: `character_encoding_server` is nota valid MySQL config variable name. I have tried to set `character_set_server` to `utf8mb4` instead, in addition to individual columns, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: There is one more step that I had to do when I changed my database to utf8mb4 and that was to STOP specifying characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;characterSetResults=UTF-8. This was actually preventing the proper handling of utf8mb4.

Comment: # For each database:
ALTER DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
# For each table:
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
# For each column:
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE column_name column_name VARCHAR(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

Comment: Bizarre that UTF-8 isn't UTF-8 until it's updated to be UTF-8

Comment: So you are suggesting that UTF-8 with 3 (three) bytes is unable to store LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH TILDE (ñ), and we need 4 (four) bytes to spell "España" correctly? Really? Could it be more inneficient than this? What can we store besides A-Z and 0-9 with 3 bytes then..

Comment: @Alex ñ takes up 2 bytes in both utf8 and utf8mb4 as long as you use varchar or text. Only characters above U+FFFF take up 4 bytes. If you don't need to store characters from different languages you can always use 1- byte encodings like latin1

Comment: Please at least stop calling `utf8mb3` `utf`

Comment: Running `SET NAMES utf8mb4;` before the `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` statement was super helpful for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42024406/470749

Comment: Thanks a lot, using changing only the table setting didn't work. I had to update the the my.cnf file

Comment: For those using mysql Workbench - hover above the table, click the configure button, select requested field and you will see at the bottom Charset/Collation options. For my use case it was a single field that was problematic, not the entire DB, so workbench was great for this

Answer (score 151):

The strings that contain `\xF0` are simply [characters encoded as multiple bytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) using UTF-8.

Although your collation is set to utf8_general_ci, I suspect that the character encoding of the **database, table or even column may be different**.  They are [independent settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341273/what-does-character-set-and-collation-mean-exactly).  Try:

```
ALTER TABLE database.table MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(255)  
    CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL;
```

Substitute whatever your actual data type is for VARCHAR(255)

Comment: Actually tried that, didn't work.  The column's data type is LONGTEXT btw, if this matters.

Comment: Your app is in Java I take it?  Try invoking Java with the `file-encoding` parameter specifying UTF-8, e.g. `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` or add an appropriate switch in your Tomcat (etc.) config file.

Comment: I suggest you put an emphasis on **"character encoding of the database, table or even column may be different"**. That is the most important thing.

Comment: You will have to alter the table as well with CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci then after change the column CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci

Comment: It worked! I wanted to store korean translations in the column. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 86):

Got the same problem, to save the data with `utf8mb4` needs to make sure:

1. `character_set_client, character_set_connection, character_set_results` are `utf8mb4`: `character_set_client` and `character_set_connection` indicate the character set in which statements are sent by the client, `character_set_results` indicates the character set in which the server returns query results to the client.
   See [charset-connection](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html).
2. the table and column encoding is `utf8mb4`

For JDBC, there are two solutions:

#### Solution 1 (need to restart MySQL):

1. modify `my.cnf` like the following and restart MySQL:

   ```
    [mysql]
    default-character-set=utf8mb4

    [mysqld]
    character-set-server=utf8mb4
    collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
   ```

this can make sure the database and `character_set_client, character_set_connection, character_set_results` are `utf8mb4` by default.

2. restart MySQL
3. change the table and column encoding to `utf8mb4`
4. STOP specifying `characterEncoding=UTF-8` and `characterSetResults=UTF-8` in the jdbc connector,cause this will override `character_set_client`, `character_set_connection`, `character_set_results` to `utf8`

#### Solution two (don't need to restart MySQL):

1. change the table and column encoding to `utf8mb4`
2. specifying `characterEncoding=UTF-8` in the jdbc connector,cause the jdbc connector doesn't suport `utf8mb4`.
3. write your sql statement like this (need to add `allowMultiQueries=true` to jdbc connector):

   ```
    'SET NAMES utf8mb4;INSERT INTO Mytable ...';
   ```

this will make sure  each connection to the server, `character_set_client,character_set_connection,character_set_results` are `utf8mb4`.
Also see [charset-connection](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html).

Comment: Point 3 was the clincher for me in conjunction with changing the db, table & field encodings: 

'SET NAMES utf8mb4;INSERT INTO Mytable ...';

Comment: Point 3 did the trick for me too, my table encoding already set to utf8mb4.

Comment: The table encoding is just a default.  It is sufficient to change the column encoding to utf8mb4.

Comment: The second approach should be used selectively, i. e. never be applied to `SELECT` queries, as `set names utf8mb4; select ... from ...` will never produce a `ResultSet` and instead result in a `ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.` error.

Comment: solution 2, just par. 1 helped me when I was trying to insert Cyrillic text through my contact form.

Comment: The Solution 2 worked for me but i am unable to get newly inserted id from my second insert query. what should i do ?

Comment: `default-character-set=utf8mb4` for the mysql client fixed it for me. `character-set-server` is optional. Quickest way to test it: `select CONVERT('' USING utf8mb4);` (edit ~/.my.cnf or /etc/my.cnf on the mysql client machine). To test only character_set_results (server-to-client part): `select CONVERT(UNHEX('F09F9883') USING utf8mb4);`. "character-set-server" only sets the default char set applied when create-database commands execute. Source: "indicate the character set and collation of the default database" https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-connection.html

Comment: For anyone using Connector/J. The document said that: "Do not issue the query SET NAMES with Connector/J, as the driver will not detect that the character set has been changed by the query, and will continue to use the character set configured when the connection was first set up.". Please see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html

Answer (score 23):

I wanted to combine a couple of posts to make a full answer of this since it does appear to be a few steps.

1. Above advice by @madtracey

`/etc/mysql/my.cnf` or `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

```
[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
##
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
init_connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Again from advice above all jdbc connections had `characterEncoding=UTF-8`and `characterSetResults=UTF-8` removed from them

With this set `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` appeared to make no difference.

I could still not write international text into db getting same failure as above

Now using this [how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27772624/755637)

Update all your db to use `utf8mb4`

```
ALTER DATABASE YOURDB CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Run this query that gives you what needs to be rung

```
SELECT CONCAT(
'ALTER TABLE ',  table_name, ' CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;  ', 
'ALTER TABLE ',  table_name, ' CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;  ')
FROM information_schema.TABLES AS T, information_schema.`COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY` AS C
WHERE C.collation_name = T.table_collation
AND T.table_schema = 'YOURDB'
AND
(C.CHARACTER_SET_NAME != 'utf8mb4'
    OR
 C.COLLATION_NAME not like 'utf8mb4%')
```

Copy paste output in editor replace all | with nothing post back into mysql when connected to correct db.

That is all that had to be done and all seems to work for me. Not the -`Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` is not enabled and it appears to work as expected

**E2A Still having an issue ?**
I certainly am in production so it turns out you do need to check over what has been done by above, since it sometimes does not work, here is reason and fix in this scenario:

```
show create table user

  `password` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
```

You can see some are still latin 
attempting to manually update the record:

```
ALTER TABLE user CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
ERROR 1071 (42000): Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

So let's narrow it down:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE user change username username varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 not NULL;
ERROR 1071 (42000): Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
mysql> ALTER TABLE user change username username varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 not NULL;
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

In short I had to reduce the size of that field in order to get the update to work.

Now when I run:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE user CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

It all works

Comment: Question: the last ALTER TABLE command will convert the contents of all VARCHAR fields into valid, genuine UTF8 encoded string? I ask because I'm having problems converting my LATIN1 fields to UTF8, specifically when the ñ character is found, conversion directly fails due to an incorrect string value (error 1366).

Comment: if you mean `ALTER TABLE user CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;` strangely enough when I ran this the final time all the fields no longer had a character set defined. so password from above became `password` varchar(255)  NOT NULL,  (nothing about encoding). This means the last command simply must have made mysql lookup what the actual table definition was and because now the table was by default this the fields no longer need it - I presume they remained with the character set simply because during the dump of entire table updates it couldn't update it and hence it was left in that state

Answer (score 12):

In my case, I tried everything above, nothing worked. I am pretty sure, my database looks like below.

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Connection id:      12
Current database:   xxx
Current user:       yo@localhost
SSL:            Not in use
Current pager:      stdout
Using outfile:      ''
Using delimiter:    ;
Server version:     5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (Ubuntu)
Protocol version:   10
Connection:     Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset:    utf8
Db     characterset:    utf8
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
UNIX socket:        /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:         42 min 49 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 372  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 166  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 30  Queries per second avg: 0.144
```

so, I look up the column charset in every table

```
show create table company;
```

It turns out the column charset is latin. That's why, I can not insert Chinese into database.

```
 ALTER TABLE company CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

That might help you. :)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem in my rails project:

```
Incorrect string value: '\xF0\xA9\xB8\xBDs ...' for column 'subject' at row1
```

Solution 1:  before saving to db convert string to base64 by    `Base64.encode64(subject)`
and after fetching from db use `Base64.decode64(subject)`

Solution 2:

Step 1: 
Change the character set (and collation) for subject column by

```
ALTER TABLE t1 MODIFY
subject VARCHAR(255)
  CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
  COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Step 2: In database.yml use

```
encoding :utf8mb4
```

Answer (score 5):

just do

```
ALTER TABLE `some_table` 
CHARACTER SET = utf8 , COLLATE = utf8_general_ci ;

ALTER TABLE `some_table` 
CHANGE COLUMN `description_with_latin_or_something` `description` TEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NOT NULL ;
```

Comment: what if I have a bunch of tables I want to change in database though? and what if all have different storage engine (innodb, etc)?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are using **phpmyadmin** to solve this error, follow these steps:

1. **phpMyAdmin**
2. **your_table**
3. **"Structure tab"**
4. change the Collation of your field from `latin1_swedish_ci` (or whatever it is) to `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: Not valid, you are supposing he uses phpMyAdmin.

Comment: doesnt work...... and the collation is changed in 'operation' and not in structure

Comment: @OlorunfemiAjibulu yes, you can change it in "structure" as well. For some people here, it worked

Comment: @TeoMihaila Perhaps, it's versioning.

Answer (score 5):

this is not the recommendation solution.. But worth to share. Since my project are upgrade the DBMS from old Mysql to newest (8). But I cant change the table structure, only the DBMS config (mysql). The solution for mysql server.

test on **Windows**
mysql **8.0.15** 
on mysql **config** search for

> sql-mode="....."

uncomment it. Or in my case just type/add

> sql-mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

why not recommended solution. because if you use latin1 (my case).. the data insert successly but not the content (mysql not respond with error!!) . for example you type info like this

> bla \x12

it save

> bla [] (box)

okay.. for my problem.. I can change the field to UTF8.. But there is small problem.. see above answer about other solution is failed because the word is not inserted because contain more than 2 bytes (cmiiw).. this solution make your insert data become box. The reasonable is to use blob.. and you can skip my answer.

Another testing related to this were.. using **utf8_encode** on your code before save. I use on latin1 and it was success (I'm not using **sql-mode**)! same as above answer using **base64_encode** .

My suggestion to analys your table requirement and tried to change from other format to UTF8

Comment: In my settings.py (Django Project), I changed to sql-mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION". It's working.

Answer (score 4):

Its mostly caused due to some unicode characters.  In my case it was the Rupee currency symbol.

To quickly fix this, I had to spot the character causing this error.  I copy pasted the entire text in a text editor like vi and replaced the troubling character with a text one.

Comment: The OP mentioned that there are a *thousand records* being inserted....

Answer (score 4):

I you only want to apply the change only for one field, you could try serializing the field

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :content

  attr_accessible :content, :title
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem with my PLAY Java application. This is my stack trace for that exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Error[Incorrect string value: '\xE0\xA6\xAC\xE0\xA6\xBE...' for column 'product_name' at row 1]
  at io.ebean.config.dbplatform.SqlCodeTranslator.translate(SqlCodeTranslator.java:52)
  at io.ebean.config.dbplatform.DatabasePlatform.translate(DatabasePlatform.java:192)
  at io.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.DmlBeanPersister.execute(DmlBeanPersister.java:83)
  at io.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.DmlBeanPersister.insert(DmlBeanPersister.java:49)
  at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.PersistRequestBean.executeInsert(PersistRequestBean.java:1136)
  at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.PersistRequestBean.executeNow(PersistRequestBean.java:723)
  at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.PersistRequestBean.executeNoBatch(PersistRequestBean.java:778)
  at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.PersistRequestBean.executeOrQueue(PersistRequestBean.java:769)
  at io.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.insert(DefaultPersister.java:456)
  at io.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.insert(DefaultPersister.java:406)
  at io.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.save(DefaultPersister.java:393)
  at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.save(DefaultServer.java:1602)
  at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.save(DefaultServer.java:1594)
  at io.ebean.Model.save(Model.java:190)
  at models.Product.create(Product.java:147)
  at controllers.PushData.xlsupload(PushData.java:67)
  at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$40(Routes.scala:690)
  at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$3.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:134)
  at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$3.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:133)
  at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$8$$anon$2$$anon$1.invocation(HandlerInvoker.scala:108)
  at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:88)
  at play.http.DefaultActionCreator$1.call(DefaultActionCreator.java:31)
  at play.core.j.JavaAction.$anonfun$apply$8(JavaAction.scala:138)
  at scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:655)
  at scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:251)
  at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:209)
  at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:289)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:29)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:29)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run$$$capture(Promise.scala:60)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala)
  at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:56)
  at play.api.libs.streams.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:70)
  at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext.execute(HttpExecutionContext.scala:48)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:68)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$KeptPromise$Kept.onComplete(Promise.scala:368)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$KeptPromise$Kept.onComplete$(Promise.scala:367)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$KeptPromise$Successful.onComplete(Promise.scala:375)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.transform(Promise.scala:29)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.transform$(Promise.scala:27)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$KeptPromise$Successful.transform(Promise.scala:375)
  at scala.concurrent.Future.map(Future.scala:289)
  at scala.concurrent.Future.map$(Future.scala:289)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$KeptPromise$Successful.map(Promise.scala:375)
  at scala.concurrent.Future$.apply(Future.scala:655)
  at play.core.j.JavaAction.apply(JavaAction.scala:138)
  at play.api.mvc.Action.$anonfun$apply$2(Action.scala:96)
  at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$flatMap$1(Future.scala:304)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transformWith$1(Promise.scala:37)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run$$$capture(Promise.scala:60)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala)
  at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
  at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
  at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
  at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:81)
  at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
  at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
  at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:43)
  at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
  at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
  at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
  at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xE0\xA6\xAC\xE0\xA6\xBE...' for column 'product_name' at row 1
  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2734)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
  at io.ebeaninternal.server.type.DataBind.executeUpdate(DataBind.java:82)
  at io.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.InsertHandler.execute(InsertHandler.java:122)
  at io.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.DmlBeanPersister.execute(DmlBeanPersister.java:73)
  ... 59 more
```

I was trying to save a record using io.Ebean. I fixed it by re creating my database with utf8mb4 collation, and applied play evolution to re create all tables so that all tables should be recreated with utf-8 collation.

```
CREATE DATABASE inventory CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 4):

Hint: On **AWS RDS** you need a new **Parameter Group** for your MySQL DB with the params (instead of editing a my.cnf)

- collation_connection: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
- collation_database: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
- collation_server: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
- character_set_client: utf8mb4
- character_set_connection: utf8mb4
- character_set_database: utf8mb4
- character_set_results: utf8mb4
- character_set_server: utf8mb4

Note: character_set_system stays "utf8"

These SQL commands do ***NOT*** WORK PERMANENTLY - only in a session:

```
set character_set_server = utf8mb4;
set collation_server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 4):

After trying many queries finally, this works

```
ALTER TABLE
table_name
CHANGE column_name column_name 
varchar(256)
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are creating a new MySQL table, you can specify the charset of all columns upon creation, and that fixed the issue for me.

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
<list-of-columns>
)
CHARSET SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

You can read more details: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-column.html

Answer (score 2):

my solution is change the column type from varchar(255) to blob

Answer (score 2):

You need to set utf8mb4 in meta html and also in your server alter tabel and set collation to utf8mb4

Answer (score 2):

Droppping schema and recreating it with `utf8mb4` character set solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I also had to drop and re-create all the database’s stored procedures (and functions too) in order that they execute within the new character set of utf8mb4.

Run:

```
SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS;
```

…to see which procedures have not been updated to the server’s new character_set_client, collation_connection and Database Collation values.

Answer (score 1):

However, it is important to note that the mysql connector driver version must be older than 5.1.47 and later.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider both sides of client-server architecture:

If you are using Java or PHP, you also need to match charset in the JODBC driver or php.ini. In my case using PHP:

default_charset = "UTF-8"

In Mysql 8.0:

character_set_server = utf8mb4
collation_connection = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing a similar issue in java and don't have the flexibility to change the charset and collate encoding of the database then this answer is for you.

> you can use the [Emoji Java](https://github.com/vdurmont/emoji-java) library (or something similar if you are not using java) to achieve the same. You can
> convert into an alias before saving/updating into the database and
> convert back to Unicode post save/update/load from database. The main
> benefit is the readability of the text even after the encoding because
> this library only aliases the emoji's rather than the whole string.

**Example code snapshot:**

**String/Unicode to Alias (Before Save/Update to DB)**

```
String str = "An awesome string with a few emojis!";
String result = EmojiParser.parseToAliases(str);
System.out.println(result);
// Prints:
// "An :grinning:awesome :smiley:string with a few :wink:emojis!"
```

**Alias to Unicode/String (After Save/Update/Load from DB)**

```
String str = "An :grinning:awesome :smiley:string &#128516;with a few :wink:emojis!";
String result = EmojiParser.parseToUnicode(str);
System.out.println(result);
// Prints:
// "An awesome string with a few emojis!"
```

> Note: You can use @PrePersist, @PreUpdate, @PostPersist, @PostUpdate,
> @PostLoad in enitity itself to do the alias and unicode conversion if
> you are using spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

I was converting a CSV file to an SQL file in Python. The data was from the 90s and some rows were corrupted. For example, where readable ASCII characters would normally be, you'd see [control characters](https://www.asciitable.com/) 0-31 and 127. Other times, you'd come across weird Unicode characters like [U+FFFD](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm).

Importing the resulting SQL file on the command line via `mysql database_name < file.sql` gave "ERROR 1366 (HY000) at line 123: Incorrect string value: 'ABC' for column 'XYZ' at row 456".

`SELECT VERSION();` showed `8.0.32-0ubuntu0.20.04.2`.

`SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';` showed:

| Variable_name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| character_set_client | utf8mb4 |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4 |
| character_set_database | utf8mb4 |
| character_set_filesystem | binary |
| character_set_results | utf8mb4 |
| character_set_server | utf8mb4 |
| character_set_system | utf8mb3 |
| collation_connection | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
| collation_database | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
| collation_server | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |

Using `SET NAMES 'UTF8MB4';` and `SET CHARACTER SET 'UTF8MB4';` didn't work. Rewriting the command to use `mysql -e "SOURCE file.sql"` didn't work. Using character set command line flags such as `mysql --default-character-set=utf8mb4` didn't work.

The only thing that worked was changing:

```py
with open('/foo/bar/baz.sql', 'w') as sql_file:
```

to:

```py
with open('/foo/bar/baz.sql', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as sql_file:
```

The problem appears to have been the encoding of the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

when you run java on windows,use `java -jar -Dfile.encoding=utf-8`,it could solve it!
Caused by:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xC0\xEB\xBF\xAA\xBC\xD2...' for column 'dsc1' at row 1
```