# Mysql UTF8 Encoding Issue - "Incorrect string value"

Tags: .net, mysql

I'm using Mysql (5.5.27) with .Net connector (6.5.4), and when i'm trying to insert some data, i'm getting following error.

```
Incorrect string value: '\xF3\xB6\xA5\x89f'...' for column 'STACK_TRACE' at row 1
```

I have already searched enough on stack overflow, and tried following charset & collation for database, table and column.

- 'utf8' 'utf8_general_ci'
- 'utf8' 'utf8_unicode_ci'
- 'utf8mb4' 'utf8mb4_general_ci'
- 'utf8mb4' 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'

I have set 'charset=utf8' in connection string properly.

- Is there any thing wrong with that particular unicode character ?  I don't have control over the data, its collected from lot of android phones.
- Is it mysql bug ?

Comment: Could you please confirm that the error still occurs when you have set table as well as database and column all to `'utf8mb4'`, and collation to `'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'`?  I'm just being sure that you tried this case, and not just a sample of the permutations of character set and collation.

Comment: @JimDeLaHunt: Surely the only one of those that matters is the column's character set?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have solved it, by doing following changes.

- used ";CharSet=utf8mb4;" in connection string. I missed this one earlier. I was using "utf8".
- set database's default charset, table's default charset and all column's charset to 'utf8mb4'
- set database's default collation, table's default collation and all column's collation to 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'

As @eggyal mentions, column charset and collation only matters, i have set all default values, so that I don't have update all new columns in future.

Answer (score 3):

The byte sequence `\xF3\xB6\xA5\x89` appears to be a valid UTF-8 byte sequence for the character U+F6949, a private use character. Note that this character is in a *supplementary plane*, and requires a 4-byte UTF-8 sequence to represent it.

The [MySQL documentation 10.1.10. *Unicode Support*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode.html) notes that before MySQL 5.5.3, the charset "utf8" only supported "one to three bytes per character".  You are using MySQL 5.5.27 (thanks for noting that), so MySQL can handle this character -- but you must use a new encoding: "`utf8mb4`, a UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode character set using one to four bytes per character". Also use the `utf8mb4` variant of the collation. Also, "Client applications that need to communicate with the server using Unicode should set the client character set accordingly; for example, by issuing a `SET NAMES 'utf8'` statement."

Don't forget to set the column to `utf8mb4` as well. The error message, "Incorrect string value... for column..." is a hint that this might be your problem.  [MySQL bug report #30131 *"Incorrect string value" error (1366) when inserting special characters*](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=30131) appears to be a similar situation. The final comment reads, "This problem solves easily. Don't forget to not only set the database, table and collation to utf8, BUT THE COLUMNS ALSO! That's what cause the problem for me. I created the table in latin, then switch to utf8, but forgot to also change the columns."

[Stack Overflow question *“Incorrect string value” when trying to insert UTF-8 into MySQL via JDBC?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957238/incorrect-string-value-when-trying-to-insert-utf-8-into-mysql-via-jdbc) appears to be about a similar problem.

Comment: The [error message](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_truncated_wrong_value_for_field) suggests that the string is *valid* in the connection character set (otherwise one would see [`ER_INVALID_CHARACTER_STRING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_invalid_character_string)), but not in the column's (which the OP says he has tried as `utf8mb4`).

Comment: Modifying the existing column fixed it for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation - *The character set named utf8 uses a maximum of three bytes per character and contains only BMP characters. As of MySQL 5.5.3, the utf8mb4 character set uses a maximum of four bytes per character supports supplemental characters...*

[The utf8mb4 Character Set (4-Byte UTF-8 Unicode Encoding)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html)

If you need to use 4-bytes UTFs, then alter table fields - set utf8mb4 charset, and set the connection - `SET NAMES utf8mb4`.

Comment: The [error message](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_truncated_wrong_value_for_field) suggests that the string is *valid* in the connection character set (otherwise one would see [`ER_INVALID_CHARACTER_STRING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_invalid_character_string)), but not in the column's (which the OP says he has tried as `utf8mb4`).