# My code changes when I insert it in MySQL

Tags: php, javascript

I used this webpage http://javascriptobfuscator.com/default.aspx to obfuscate a small script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#likee").fadeOut("fast");
});
```

And the obfuscated code is:

```
$(document)["\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79"](function (){$("\x23\x6C\x69\x6B\x65\x65")["\x66\x61\x64\x65\x4F\x75\x74"]("\x66\x61\x73\x74");} );
```

I am using a form to insert the obfuscated code into mysql. However, when I inserted the code I got this:

```
$(document)["x72x65x61x64x79"](function (){$("x23x6Cx69x6Bx65x65")["x66x61x64x65x4Fx75x74"]("x66x61x73x74");} );
```

Does anybody know why backslashes are removed?

Will my code work without backslashes?

Comment: did you `mysql(i)_real_escape_string` your input first?

Comment: no. `"x23"` is something COMPLETELY different from `"\x23"`. one's 3 letters (x,2,3), the other is a single character.

Comment: add your php code also

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has something to do with the encoding. I guess that you are using the utf8 encoding format for the text/varchar (or some sort) column where the data is inserted in.

The utf8 encoding format only accepts unicode characters that can be represented with 3 bytes, but the \x23 character needs 4 bytes, so mysql strips the character.

How to solve? 
Do you have mysql 5.5 or later? You can change the column encoding from utf8 to utf8mb4. This encoding allows characters of 4 bytes.

Source: ["Incorrect string value" when trying to insert UTF-8 into MySQL via JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957238/incorrect-string-value-when-trying-to-insert-utf-8-into-mysql-via-jdbc)