# Incorrect string value: '\xF0\X9F... and I use utf8mb4 got ? in mysql

Tags: mysql, utf-8, utf8mb4

the source character is "in check" which one of our app users added, and i can't figure out what it is actually.

i used way of this link (["Incorrect string value" when trying to insert UTF-8 into MySQL via JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957238/incorrect-string-value-when-trying-to-insert-utf-8-into-mysql-via-jdbc)) to solve the problem when i insert special characters into mysql via jdbc.

but when sql exception ws gone, i find my characters inserted into mysql are like this "? in check"

can anybody help me slove this problem? thanks

Comment: Where do you see the output with question mark? Use the `HEX` function to confirm that the column actually stores a question mark and it's not just that the client software decides not to show it.

Comment: actually the column stores something else when imported via jdbc , but i can't store it correctly in mysql. so how can i solve this problem?

Comment: What is that something else that the database stores?

Comment: "in check" this is the data i got from cassandra, and this is a ugc, so i cannot exactly know "". My task is to store this user data into mysql without change.

Comment: What does ugc mean? What happens when you store this string in MySQL, what is actually stored in the column? If you're asking what that character is, it's an emoji for a bag of money