# PHP / MySQL special characters issue

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters, collation

I'm facing an issue with the special characters. I'm taking information from a DB in MSSQL which returns in php a value which may contain specials characters like "à é ö ü" etc. In my sample, I will use the city name of Zürich and when I try to insert this information into a MySQL database, I get the following error :

"Incorrect string value: '\xFCrich ...' for column..."

so, I've done the following but it still showing the same error message:

```
$arrSearch = array('\xE4','\xF6','\xFC','\xC4','\xD6','\xDC','\xDF');
$arrReplace = array('ä','ö','ü','Ä','Ö','Ü','ß',);
$City=str_replace($arrSearch, $arrReplace, $City);
```

If I do an echo of $City, I get the following :
    Z�rich (rectangular block)

I've tried as well hex2bin() but I just get a white page and nothing is inserted into Database. FYI, DB collation is in utf8mb4_general_ci and setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_EN') is set in php file. All php files are encoded into UTF8 and chatset is set as follow : mysql_set_charset('utf8mb4',$link);

I must admit, I'm a bit lost. Does anyone has a clue on how to fix this?
Thanks.

EDIT: The server hosting this app is running under 2008R2/IIs 7.5 and I've found this KB by Microsoft. I'll try the hotfix and the registry modification but it didnt work. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2277918/

Comment: have you tried w/o replacing the characters and putting UTF8 metatag in view side?

Comment: cant you just change collation of your database to utf8 unicode?

Comment: Change your collation to UTF-8 and these problems will go away. `ü` and `\FC` are the same thing to MySQL, which is why your fix isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got it! Was so stupid.... I'm using FPDF with that insertion and to show special characters properly in FPDF, I had to set an iconv('UTF-8', $charset, $_REQUEST['City']);
Sorry and thanks again for assistance! now works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Set the character set to utf8.

Comment: I've change the collation to utf8_general_ci, kept it as it comes from the MsSQL database (Zürich), added "mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link)" and problem still the same. Did I miss something?

Comment: trying to add utf8 php header.
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Comment: Try to change the php file encoding.

Comment: I fix that but still the same. Any other suggestion? :)

Comment: Can you change the database's latin1_general_ci encoding?

Comment: still the same error message. I've added again the str_replace and it's the same error message again : Incorrect string value: '\xFCrich ...'

Comment: Look this article:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957238/incorrect-string-value-when-trying-to-insert-utf-8-into-mysql-via-jdbc

Comment: Still doing the same error message. I've tried as well by changing the mysql_set_charset('utf8mb4',$link); but still doing the same error message.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any idea. :S

Comment: no worries, thanks a lot for trying! :) It's getting me crazy.