# Forcing Zlib::Deflate.deflate UTF-8 3 bytes

Tags: ruby

According to ["Incorrect string value" when trying to insert UTF-8 into MySQL via JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957238/incorrect-string-value-when-trying-to-insert-utf-8-into-mysql-via-jdbc) , if I want to store data that contains 4-byted UTF-8 characters, mysql's column need to have a `utf8mb4` encoding.

I'm using `Zlib::Deflate.deflate` to compress a string and would like to store it in Mysql.

Upon inserting the record, I get the following:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Incorrect string value: '\x96Iv$!\x0C...'
```

So basically, I will either have to change the column's encoding or force `Zlib::Deflat.deflate` to generate only 3-byted UTF-8 characters. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing the data as a `UTF-8` string, I changed the column type to [`BLOB`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html) and stored the data as binary.

Note to self and others: if you want to store `Zlib` inflated data, make sure the column type is `BLOB` in `mysql`.