# django encoding to utf8 not working

Tags: python, mysql, django, utf-8

I am a bit stuck here. I have this code, which unescapes html elements inside the text and encodes it into utf8.

```
import HTMLParser

def clean_text(text):
    htmlparser = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
    return htmlparser.unescape(
        ' '.join(text.replace('\n', '').split())
    ).replace(';', ',').encode('utf-8').strip()
```

and I am using mysql (God save me from it!)

and this code is running in two projects. in first project, the code works well, no problems. In the other project, the string will be saved like this:

```
Die Verbindungen zwischen Dinosauriern und VÃ¶geln immer stÃ¤rker
```

It should be

```
Die Verbindungen zwischen Dinosauriern und Vögeln immer stärker
```

I am using in both projects django 1.7 and python 2.7.9

what am I missing? mysql collocation is `utf8_general_ci` and chatset is `utf8`. both mysql dbs are the same in settings.

it would be a miracle to solve this issue... I give a warm hug and kiss if someone could help me debug this thing

Comment: Do you expect the ouput of `clean_text` to be `unicode` or `bytes`/`str`?

Comment: @bgusach good question! str I think :)

Comment: I think you should understand what are the expected inputs and the outputs of your function. I would say if you want to store in the DB, you don't have to take care of the encoding, and just pass unicode objects (i.e. no  `encode` is needed).

Comment: @bgusach tried, but the same result

Comment: Where and how are you getting the unexpected result?

Comment: the string is still not being saved as utf8 @bgusach

Answer (score 0):

`Vögeln` --> `VÃ¶geln` is an example of Mojibake

- The bytes you have in the client are correctly encoded in utf8 (good).
- You connected with `SET NAMES latin1` (or `set_charset('latin1')` or ...), probably by default.  (It should have been `utf8`.)
- The column in the tables may or may not have been `CHARACTER SET utf8`, but it should have been that.

Perhaps useful:  [Django character latin1 mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28523138/django-character-latin1-mysql) [Incorrect string value in python+django+Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28652295/incorrect-string-value-in-pythondjangomysql/)

Checklist for Python:

- `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` -- (for literals in code)
- `charset='utf8'` in `connect()` call -- Is that buried in `bottle_mysql.Plugin`?  (Note: Try 'utf-8' and 'utf8')
- Text encoded in utf8.
- No need for encode() or decode() if you are willing to accept utf8 everywhere.
- `u'...'` for literals
- `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` near start of html page
- Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8  (in HTTP response header)
- header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');  (in PHP to get that response header)
- `CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci` on column (or table) definition in MySQL.
- [[[UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through/279279#279279][utf8) all the way through]]
- Use MySQL Connector/Python instead of pyodbc and MySQL Connector/ODBC

(@DanielRoseman -- Have I stated anything incorrectly?)

Answer (score -1):

On top of your file mention encoding `# coding: utf-8` and it will work like charm.

Comment: does it really read `# coding: utf-8`? because I know only `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` and I have it already in it

Comment: I used your code and specified the coding and it worked. :)

Comment: I think this is an ambiguous answer to an ambiguous question.

Comment: **Please** don't randomly recommend this. The coding declaration only affects literal text within the code itself; this question is asking about retrieving text from the database, where a coding declaration will have no effect at all.