# How to solve error inserting into table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to fix this error. Current PHP MySQL library version 5.1.72 and  collation is utf8_general_ci

```
Error inserting into table: notes: Query Failed: INSERT INTO notes (id,date_entered,date_modified,modified_user_id,created_by,name,file_mime_type,filename,parent_type,parent_id,portal_flag,embed_flag,deleted)

VALUES 
('caff0041-48a4-218d-c596-566a8b42549b','2015-12-11 08:38:26','2015-12-11 08:38:26','e982b37c-4773-11e3-9be9-00215aeeb772','e982b37c-4773-11e3-9be9-00215aeeb772','OutlookEmoji-.png','image/PNG','OutlookEmoji-.png','Emails','c1ba0bf7-cb38-701a-270e-566a8b7a23c2',0,0,0): MySQL error 1366: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x8A.p...' for column 'name' at row 1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: issue in your name character. Make database collation as utf-8

Comment: @ChetanAmeta we already have utf8_general_ci collation.

Answer (score 0):

Make database collation as `utf-8` for your database.

You are getting error because, you are inserting `OutlookEmoji-.png`

After changing the collation, run the query.

Comment: PHP MySQL library version 5.1.72 and current collation is utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you trying to insert an invalid character in the field name: OutlookEmoji-.png

Comment: Ya but I cant fix, Now the database not connecting through this error in log.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. When you post an answer you should also indicate a possible solution or you can state explicitly that there is no possible solution,  read also this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

[This may answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957238/incorrect-string-value-when-trying-to-insert-utf-8-into-mysql-via-jdbc). Namely,

> If you have MySQL 5.5 or later you can change the column encoding from
>   utf8 to utf8mb4. This encoding allows storage of characters that
>   occupy 4 bytes in UTF-8.

However you have 5.1,

> Although your collation is set to utf8_general_ci, I suspect that the
>   character encoding of the database, table or even column may be
>   different. They are independent settings.

Comment: I need to fix this error at this time, Any solutions to (OutlookEmoji-.png) remove or change it?

Comment: If the note you are inserting is not important then worry about it later. But make a log of all the notes you didn't insert. Then when you have time either upgrade mysql or try one of those answers.