# remove 4 byte UTF8 characters

Tags: c#, regex, utf-8

I'd like to remove 4 byte UTF8 characters which starts with \xF0 (the char with the ASCII code 0xF0) from a string and tried

```
sText = Regex.Replace (sText, "\xF0...", "");
```

This doesn't work. Using two backslashes did not work neither.

The exact input is the content of https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Spezial:Exportieren&action=submit&pages=Unicode The 4 byte character ist the one after the text "[[Violinschlüssel]] ", in hex notation: .. 0x65 0x6c 0x5d 0x5d 0x20 0xf0 0x9d 0x84 0x9e 0x20 .. The expected output is 0x65 0x6c 0x5d 0x5d 0x20 0x20 ..

What's wrong?

Comment: Use two backslashes.

Comment: Maybe because you tried to remove [`ð` character](https://ideone.com/YizDeh). What is your exact input and exact expected output?

Comment: Comments are for _us_ to ask _you_ for clarification. Please put your clarifications in the question itself, by clicking the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38714663/edit) link and updating your post.

Comment: This is a good question. It concerns the non-obvious relation between bytes, characters and strings in C#.

Comment: The exact input is not clear, please put it into a string literal. For now, have a look at https://ideone.com/IDPqHP

Comment: Try `[\uF000-\uFFFFF]+` with the Regex.Replace.

Comment: [\uF000-\uFFFFF]+ doesn't work.

Comment: I'm curious, why are the Unicode codepoints that UTF-8 encodes to 4-bytes (U+10000 to U+10FFFF) special to you? And, why do you describe them in terms of bytes and not codepoint ranges or Unicode blocks (or—not quite the same thing—Unicode categories)?

Comment: I need to store the data in a MySQL database with "UTF8" encoding (which can't be changed for the moment).

Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957238/incorrect-string-value-when-trying-to-insert-utf-8-into-mysql-via-jdbc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such characters will be *surrogate pairs* in .NET which uses UTF-16. Each of them will be *two* UTF-16 code units, that is two `char` values.

To just remove them, you can do (`using System.Linq;`):

```
sText = string.Concat(sText.Where(x => !char.IsSurrogate(x)));
```

(uses an overload of `Concat` introduced in .NET 4.0 (Visual Studio 2010)).

---

Late addition: It may give better performance to use:

```
sText = new string(sText.Where(x => !char.IsSurrogate(x)).ToArray());
```

even if it looks worse. (Works in .NET 3.5 (Visual Studio 2008).)

Comment: As far as I understand it removes all 3 and 4 byte UTF8 characters (which are 2 UTF16 char values in C# strings). This is not exactly what I asked for, but I found out that this is exactly what I really require. Thanks again.

Comment: @André You are wrong. If you want to remove characters that correspond to 3 byte UTF-8 or longer, just use `sText = string.Concat(sText.Where(x => x < '\u0800'));`. UTF-8 may be used in files, but it is not used by .NET or Windows once the `string` is in memory. If a character requires 1, 2, or 3 bytes in UTF-8, it can fit in one single _code unit_ (that is one single `char` value) in UTF-16 which is the encoding used internally by .NET and Windows. If a character requires 4 bytes in UTF-8, it needs two UTF-16 _code units_ (so _two_ `char` values); these two make up a "surrogate pair".

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to search for `byte` values but C# strings are made from `char` values. The C# language spec at section "2.4.4.4 Character literals" states:

> A character literal represents a single character, and usually consists of a character in quotes, as in 'a'.
>   ...
>   A hexadecimal escape sequence represents **a single Unicode character**, with the value formed by the hexadecimal number following `\x`.

Hence the search for `"\xF0..."` is searching for the character `U+F0` which would be represented by the bytes `C3 B0`.

If you want find replace all Unicode characters whose first byte is 0xF0 then I believe you need to search for the character values whose first byte if 0xFO.

The character `U+10000` is represented as `F0 90 80 80` (the preceding code is `U+FFFF` which is `EF BF BF`). The first code with `F1 .... ..` is `U+40000` which is `F1 80 80 80` and the value before it is `U+3FFFF` which is `F0 BF BF BF`.

Hence you need to remove characters in the range `U+10000` to `U+3FFFF`. This should be possible with a regular expression such as

```
sText = Regex.Replace (sText, "[\\x10000-\\x3FFFF]", "");
```

---

The relevant characters from the source quoted in the question have been extracted into the code below. The code then tries to understand how the characters are held in strings.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = "]  (";
    Console.Write("Input length  {0} : '{1}'  : ", input.Length, input);
    foreach (char cc in input)
    {
        Console.Write("  {0,2:X02}", (int)cc);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

The output from the program is as below. This supports the *surrogate pair* explanation given by @Jeppe in his answer.

```
Input length  6 : '] ?? ('  :   5D  20  D834  DD1E  20  28
```

Comment: @Qix Why do you want to modify a direct  quotation from the language standard? The quoted section does not have any bold text and its uses string quotes. Please explain.

Comment: Because it better emphasizes your point. It's not changing the meaning of the spec. I had to search for the reason why you were including the notation of a single character and had to search for the _real_ answer, which is the distinction between a unicode `char` and a single `byte`.

Comment: @Qix The first sentence of my answer refers to the difference between `char` and `byte` in C.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This most likely points into the right direction, but your solution still doesn't work. It removes a lot of characters from the input, but not the 4 byte UTF8 characters. Even `Regex.Replace (sText, "\\x1D11E", "")` does not remove the precise single character from the input.