# Error Code: 1366 && 1300 - MySQL CHARACTER SET Issue

Tags: mysql, sql, character-encoding

I have two character set bugs that are preventing me from seeding my database with an old database's contents.

**1. Error Code 1366: Incorrect string value "\xDB"**

I've tried changing the `CHARACTER SET` of my `TABLE` to `utf8mb4`.

I've looked into what \xDB would be as a character type, and stumbled upon [this](https://www.charbase.com/00db-unicode-latin-capital-letter-u-with-circumflex). This lead me to believe it's a Javascript escape format. However, I can't seem to find a MySQL `CHARACTER SET` that supports this.

Even if I do find a `CHARACTER SET` that supports Javascript escape format, wouldn't it be best to convert everything to the more standard and all encompassing `utf8mb4`? How would this be done?

**2. Error Code 1300: Invalid utf8mb4 character string**

This is the offending character: ®

Again, I've tried similar things as mentioned above, with little success.

**EDIT:**

I set the `CHARACTER SET` in a new database as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
    `product_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
    `product_line` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `product_num` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `description` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 ;
```

**EDIT 2:**

I didn't know this made a difference, but the problem was arising while doing a `LOAD DATA INFILE` as follows:

```
USE `inventory`;

LOAD DATA INFILE
'all_products.csv'
INTO TABLE `products`
    FIELDS
        TERMINATED BY ','
        OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES
        TERMINATED BY ',\r\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(`product_line`,`product_num`,`description`);
```

Comment: Are you aware that changing the table's default character set does not change the character set of the existing columns? You need `ALTER TABLE ... CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET ...` for that. Refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html under heading "Changing the Character Set"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not blindly do `ALTER ... CONVERT TO ...`; it could make things worse.  If you have already made a "correction" to the already incorrect situation, then any advice I give below is not likely to undo the *two* problems you have.

`®` and `DB` do not map to one-another.

`DB`, in various character sets represents:

```
                                    macce   2  1 'Ř'
                           cp1250, latin2   2  1 'Ű'
                           cp1257, latin7   2  1 'Ū'
                     dec8, latin1, latin5   2  1 'Û'
                                      hp8   2  1 'Ü'
```

Meanwhile, `AE`:

```
cp1250, cp1251, cp1256, cp1257, geostd8,
           hebrew, latin1, latin5, latin7   2  1 '®'
                                    macce   2  1 'ģ'
                                      hp8   2  1 'Û'
                                   latin2   2  1 'Ž'
                    cp850, cp852, keybcs2   2  1 '«'
```

The usual error involves specifying `latin1` in one place, but `utf8`/`utf8mb4` in another.

(For the sake of this discussion, utf8 and utf8mb4 act the same.)

[*This*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) discusses typical problems.  I am worried that either there has been an incorrect correction that muddied the situation or the single character is not enough for diagnosing.  See [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases) for the available fixes and which cases they apply to.

Comment: This lead me a solution, for this I award you the bounty. Is there a resource you @Rick used to find what character codes map to the other? I noticed that both codes I am using map to `latin1`. Thus, for those wondering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41922029/load-data-infile-invalid-ut8mb4-character-string) question lead me to realize I need to set the `character set` in the `LOAD DATA INFILE`

Comment: @Neil - I have collected the latin1:utf8 encodings here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#8_bit_encodings   The list of mappings for DB and AE came from a special script that went through the character sets doing `CONVERT(CONVERT(UNHEX('AE') USING ...) USING utf8mb4)` (plus some pretty-printing).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the collation to `utf8_unicode_ci`? Also, there are two important settings in your `my.cnf` file. They are:

```
collation-server
character-set-server
```

Also, I totally agree with @Rick you should avoid `ALTER ... CONVERT TO ...`. Try to execute before inserting:

```
SET NAMES utf8_unicode_ci
```

Does this help?