# mysql Incorrect string value for a column

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `msg` (
  `content` varchar(255)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And trying to insert the string 'I  You':

```
INSERT INTO `msg` (`content`) VALUES ('I  You');
```

But getting error:

```
Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x92\x9A Y...' for column 'content' at row 1
```

I think UTF-8 can accommodate any characters. Then why this error?

Comment: I'd say you'd need to convert to `TEXT` rather than `VARCHAR` to be honest. Judging from the error thrown its over your limit.

Comment: You might want to check this answer [“Incorrect string value” when trying to insert UTF-8 into MySQL via JDBC?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957238/incorrect-string-value-when-trying-to-insert-utf-8-into-mysql-via-jdbc)