# How to import huge data from excel to MySql

Tags: mysql, import

Today I tried importing 44.555 row from excel files to MySql database using heidiSQL, but why only 1.662 imported to database

[two last row in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Rykh.jpg)

[All row result in mysql only 6 x 1.662](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oq5fx.png)

What is the maximum number of rows that Mysql can handle?

[import window heiSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBwk2.png)

finaly , all 44.554 rows imported to database, open csv file with notepad, save as with encoding utf8 then csv ready to import..

Comment: MySQL's max row count is not 44K rows, assuming you don't have massive information in each row.  Please post your exact error message.

Comment: Please add your `import` code.

Comment: there is no error message when importing the csv files, import was succesed, but when i check with query SELECT in database, the result row have diffrent number with original in csv files.

Comment: @jitendra : i dont import with code , im using heidiSQL with csv files

Comment: If you have a PRIMARY or a UNIQUE KEY on the table and you use `INSERT IGNORE` or `REPLACE` in HeidiSQL, then some rows can be ignored or replaced. Please post a screenshot of your import window.

Comment: in bottom panel log command HeidiSQL it said :                           LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL INFILE 'F:\\Toegoemlyo\\Documents\\upload_db\\jaminan.csv' INTO TABLE `test`.`migrasi` CHARACTER SET utf8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (`no_label`, `nama_debitur`, `rek_loan`, `jaminan`, `mbu`, `tgl_terima`);
/* SQL Error (1300): Invalid utf8 character string: '' */ , what is that mean ??

Comment: @paul Spiegel : screenshot posted

Comment: Invalid utf8 character string : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408012/mysql-invalid-utf8-character-string-when-importing-csv-table