# MYSQL UTF8MB4 keep showing ???? character

Tags: mysql, utf-8, cjk, utf8mb4

I would like to save extra rare Chinese character in database using mysql,
however keep showing ???? after the text is inserted into the table.
Previously I have searched how to insert any 4byte Chinese character into mysql data, and following the process (["Incorrect string value" when trying to insert UTF-8 into MySQL via JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957238/incorrect-string-value-when-trying-to-insert-utf-8-into-mysql-via-jdbc)) but still no use. Is there something I miss?

Fyi, I have updated mysql version into 5.7.18, and I try to insert the extra rare Chinese character from phpmyadmin directly.
thanks in advance!

Comment: You only mention utf8mb4, without giving the least information about how you are using it.

Comment: What kind information do you need? I just want to save 4byte character into my table

Comment: I'm confused. Do you mean that you haven't tried anything? You just installed MySQL and tried with whatever default settings there are?

Comment: No, I just upgraded mysql into latest version due to my previous mysql version is less than 5.5. I updated due to suggestion from link above, 
I have tried to configure the charset and collation variable into utf8mb4, however the retrieved data still showing ???? character. Please advise

Answer (score 1):

As per the [CREATE TABLE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html):

> ```
> CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] tbl_name
>     (create_definition,...)
>     [table_options]
>     [partition_options]
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> table_option:
>     ENGINE [=] engine_name
>   | AUTO_INCREMENT [=] value
>   | AVG_ROW_LENGTH [=] value
>   | [DEFAULT] CHARACTER SET [=] charset_name
> ```

In other words:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
   some_column VARCHAR(100)
)
CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4;
```

It won't hurt either to pick a specific collation.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, but I have changed the database server, table name, and respective column into collation utf8mb4, but could it be the problem due to my column type is text not varchar the issue?

Comment: A `TEXT` column with `utf8mb4` charset can store the same characters than a `VARCHAR` column with `utf8mb4` charset.

Answer (score 1):

You also must change the connection to be utf8mb4.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored for discussion of "question marks".

Note:  The data failed to be stored correctly; it cannot be recovered without re-inserting the data.

Comment: Thanks, I have checked the connection and it seems my font not supported for this extra rare Chinese character.
I just found the link for this extra rare Chinese character in here,
https://www.download-free-fonts.com/details/90428/simsun-founder-extended