# Squeryl utf8mb4 support

Tags: mysql, scala, utf-8, utf8mb4, squeryl

I'm using [Squeryl](http://squeryl.org/index.html) to work with a MySQL database. The tables are in utf8mb4 encoding. Now I want to insert some **utf8 (4 byte)** strings into the db through Squeryl. How do I do that?

I tried to set `?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8` to my connection url but apparently, `UTF-8` here is **3 byte** to MySQL so it doesn't work.

I found [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35156926/3778765), but after some digging, I don't see anyway to append my queries with `SET NAMES utf8mb4;` (changing database config and environment is not an option)

Example string: `อลิซร้องเพลงตามเลยค่ะ`

Error when trying to insert the string:

`Exception in thread "main" org.squeryl.SquerylSQLException: Exception while executing statement : Incorrect string value`

Comment: Is there a `charset=utf8mb4` argument in addition to `?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8`?

Comment: Sadly no according to [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) about Configuration Properties (see at the bottom)

Comment: And you can't execute `SET NAMES utf8mb4` right after connecting?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure not to connect as `root`.

Have this in `my.cnf` (in the `[mysqld]` section)

```
init_connect = SET NAMES utf8mb4
```