# MySql Incorrect string value even with utf8mb4

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

Mysql version : 8.0.12 on WAMP Server (apache 2.4.33)

In my.ini I added (then restarted mysql multiple times):

```
[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

I have a mysql table `stores` with a column `coordinates    varchar(255)    utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.

**I get this error while trying to update `stores` column:**

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xFAC3OJ]...' for column 'coordinates' at row 1 (SQL: update `stores` set `updated_at` = 2018-09-12 11:01:48, `coordinates` = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-117.161084 32.715738)') where `id` = 3)
```

What am I doing wrong?

I tried the query directly in the phpMyAdmin and I get the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Incorrect string value" when trying to insert UTF-8 into MySQL via JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957238/incorrect-string-value-when-trying-to-insert-utf-8-into-mysql-via-jdbc)

Comment: How is this possible duplicate as I mentioned I added `utf8mb4` to my.ini and my column is utf8mb4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data type for column `coordinates` should not be a string,
as in `varchar(255)`, but a geometry.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-type-overview.html