# How to copy special character from one table to another table in mysql by using java

Tags: java, mysql

I'm migrating my database and now I want to transfer old table's data into new table(s)

There is one table which contains some hindi texts. I tried below step while connecting to database as

```
jdbc:mysql://locathost:3306/db_dump?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNulluseUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

and facing below error while reading/writing data as:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xE0\xA4\x95\xE0\xA4\x82...' for column 'title' at row 1
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2825)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2156)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2459)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2376)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2360)
```

Comment: have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10959780/2551236