# Using ExecuteSqlCommand makes my password not work when inserting to DB

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core

I'm using MySql DB and trying to create a user there. The password is a hash.
When I use the Context.Useraccount.add(User) and Context.SaveChanges() adding to the database works just fine, but using ExecuteSqlCommmand makes the password not work.

```
var sql = @"INSERT INTO useraccount
           (UserId,UserName,Password,CustomerId,PasswordSalt,CreatedDate)
                VALUES
                (@UserId, @UserName,@Password,@CustomerId, @PasswordSalt, @CreatedDate)";

        int rows = _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
                sql,
                new MySqlParameter("@UserId", user.UserId),
                new MySqlParameter("@UserName", user.UserName),
                new MySqlParameter("@Password", user.Password),
                new MySqlParameter("@CustomerId", user.CustomerId),
                new MySqlParameter("@PasswordSalt", user.PasswordSalt),
                new MySqlParameter("@CreatedDate", MySQLFormatDate));
```

It gives this exception: {MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Incorrect string value: '\x90]\x0E\x80\xB1\xFF...' for column 'Password' at row 1 ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Incorrect string value: '\x90]\x0E\x80\xB1\xFF...' for column 'Password' at row 1

I tried changing the Column value in the DB to varbinary (from varchar)  and then I can insert it, but it becomes a blob in the DB and it doesn't work when I try to read it again.

How can I send the hash correctly to the DB?

Edit--- 
code for creating the hash

```
 private static void CreatePasswordHash(string password, out byte[] passwordHash, out byte[] passwordSalt)
    {
        if (password == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("password");
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password)) throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be empty or whitespace only string.", "password");

        using (var hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512())
        {
            passwordSalt = hmac.Key;
            passwordHash = hmac.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
        }
    }
```

edit2---
password types are byte[]

[This is if I change the Password and SaltedPassword types in the database to VarBinary. When I use VarChar it gives the error which I pasted before and nothing gets sent to the DB.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnRT6.png)

[Text Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKWqV.png)

UPDATE -- SOLVED

So I had the wrong value in the modelbuilder.entity for the password I had VarChar there when it should've been VarBinary. 
Somehow it worked with Context.Useraccount.add(User) and Context.SaveChanges() though.

Thanks to everyone for the help!

Comment: There's obviously an issue with how you are hashing the password. Please post the hashing code.

Comment: What is the datatype of `user.Password`? What is an example value? And what do you see when you check an example value in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Password hashes are byte arrays, and cannot be stored in a C# string. They also have to be stored in a `BINARY` (or `VARBINARY`) column in the database, not a `VARCHAR` column.

> but it becomes a blob in the DB and it doesn't work when I try to read it again

To verify the user's password, you should read back the password salt (as a `byte[]`), hash the (plain text) password with the same salt, then compare the newly-generated hash to the password hash retrieved from the database (as a `byte[]`). Do not try to convert the password hash back to a C# `string`.

Comment: I'm only doing this:  var user = _context.Useraccount.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserName == username) When I'm trying to authenticate And I get this error -----------------{System.InvalidOperationException: An exception occurred while reading a database value for property 'Useraccount.Password'. The expected type was 'System.Byte[]' but the actual value was of type 'System.Byte[]'. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.String'.

Comment: But as mentioned before if I use Context.Useraccount.add(User) and Context.SaveChanges() everything works fine and there is no values with black backgrounds in the text in DB...

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to deserialize `Password` back to a `string`; you may need to change your `User` model to change the type of the property to a `byte[]`. (I would also rename the property to `PasswordHash` to make it clear you're not storing _actual_ passwords.)

Comment: Passwords are of type byte[]. I'm not trying to deserialize it to a string. Just trying to authenticate.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that's causing the error, and the exception details with the full call stack.

Answer (score 0):

Paraphrasing the answer from this answer since it applies to your situation as well

["Incorrect string value" when trying to insert UTF-8 into MySQL via JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957238/incorrect-string-value-when-trying-to-insert-utf-8-into-mysql-via-jdbc)

MySql's utf8 encoding only supports characters that can be encoded in 3 Bytes. Whatever character '\x90]\x0E\x80\xB1\xFF' is probably takes more than 3 bytes to encode and that is why MySql is yelling at you.

Verify that whatever method you are using to encode these passwords is limited to a utf8 format and that should prevent this error from re-occuring.

I can't see your method for hashing these, but this will ensure you are encoding using utf8

```
   byte[] salt = // Salt
   byte[] encodedValue = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
   byte[] saltedValue = value.Concat(salt).ToArray();
   byte[] hashedValue = SHA256Managed().ComputeHash(saltedValue);
```