# Smiley Translation error in MySQL workbench Migration Wizard

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mysql-workbench

I have an issue while migrating the data from MS SQL to Mysql using MySQL Migration Wizard.Following is the error that i got during the migration.

"Inserting Data: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x91\x8D' for column 'UserResponse' at row 20" . I did check the data in MS SQL and found there are so many smileys in the columns. I have changed the character set and collation in the destination(Mysql) table. But it did'nt do any good.

Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x91\x8D' for column 'UserResponse' at row 20

Comment: Please show the collation for the source and destination tables/columns. Also, can you show the script created by the Migration Wizard?

Comment: *"I have changed the character set and collation"* changed to what ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Incorrect string value" when trying to insert UTF-8 into MySQL via JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957238/incorrect-string-value-when-trying-to-insert-utf-8-into-mysql-via-jdbc)