# how to save instagram biography texts with symbols in mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js, database

I'm building a personal project that saves information of a user of instagram in mysql database. I am using reactJS as client and node.js as server side technology. my problem is that sometimes some people have some icon images and symbols in their profile along with text. something like this for example : `a bio with  symbol`.

when I try to save this text in mysql database I get following Error message :

```
Incorrect string value: '\\xF0\\x9F\\x8D\\x93' for column 'biography' at row 1
```

it's good to add that my biography column character is set to `utf8mb4`

what do you suggest for solving this problem and saving this information in mysql database??

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/10959780/11125492

Comment: @dev_junwen one of the solutions worked and now I can save symbols with query in mysql workbench but when I send biography text via orm to my database it stills gives me the same error...