# Incorrect string value: \'\\xC3\' for column \'description\' at row 1 in mySql

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Here, In my table, I've one column name as `description`.

As per my error, I've tried many solutions from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957238/incorrect-string-value-when-trying-to-insert-utf-8-into-mysql-via-jdbc) to change the collation type.

I've tried below collection

```
1) utf8mb4_unicode_ci
2) utf8_general_ci
```

Here, SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM your_table;

[image]

Can anyone know what is the right collation for  `\'\\xC3\'` this type of string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To support full UTF-8 Unicode like for example emojis in your case it is the character À you should use utf8mb4 and utf8mb4_unicode_ci utf8 is outdated.

You can find a full explanation at https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4.

You can check the current collations of your table like this:

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM your_table;
```

I assume your description column has type TEXT otherwise you might need to change the type.

To alter the table default character set you can use:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

But this does not change the collation of your column.
To change the collation of your column you should use:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table MODIFY description TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Well explained :) I followed your inscription but still I'm getting same error. see my edit answer I've uploaded  `SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM your_table;`

Comment: I do not have any experience with Laravel but maybe you need to change the collation and charset in your database configuration so that you connect with charset utf8mb4 and  collation utf8mb4_unicode_ci. See https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database#read-and-write-connections.

Comment: I followed another way as whatever string I get I convert that string  base64_encode and store it as a string. while fetch to show I convert base64_decode. Thank you for you kind help :)

Comment: No problem happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this first

```
ALTER TABLE your_database_name.your_table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8
```

**OR** If above solution won't work then do the following after connecting to your database

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';
SET CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in the same problem for so long. Then this function helped me

```
function replacebadchar($str) {
    global $conn;
    $str = UConverter::transcode($str, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');
    $str = UConverter::transcode($str, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', ['to_subst' => '?']);
    $str = UConverter::transcode($str, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', ['to_subst' => '?']);
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $str);
}
```